# Adobe Media Server Administration API get contents

Tags: php, api, get, administration, adobe-media-server

I'm trying to obtain data from my Adobe Media server.  For instance when I navigate with my browser to this URL:

http://misite.com:1111/admin/getLiveStreamStats?auser=myuname&apswd=mypwd&appInst=live&stream=srd

`misite.com` should be `localhost`.  I get the contents shown in my browser.   Now I'm trying to get those contents inside my php file:

```
$url = 'http://misite.com:1111/admin/ping?auser=myuname&apswd=mypwd';
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
echo $contents;

//OR:

print($contents)
```

But this gives me only a blank page. I've checked my source code and it returns empty.  What should I do?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$url = 'http://misite.com:1111/admin/ping?auser=myuname&apswd=mypwd';
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
echo $contents;
```

This has no file to refer to. Notice ping is not ping.php

```
$url = 'http://example.com/somephpscript.php?auser=myuname&apswd=mypwd';
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
echo $contents;
```

Comment: Oke, is there any sollution so i can grab this data?